# Improving save/load performance with large arrays of structures in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, performance, matlab, serialization

I have a very large array of structs (more than 100k structs) that have to be saved to a file. Later, these have to be loaded and processed one at a time. The current approach is to save it using just `save`. This takes ~8s to save and ~100s to load.

I've tried a couple of ways to speed this up:

1. Using the `-v6` flags with `save`. This sped things up, but not significantly.
2. Serializing and deserializing using `getByteStreamFromArray()` and `getArrayFromByteStream()` respectively. This had no effect. Specifically, serializing and deserializing took just as long as simply saving and loading.
3. (still working on this) Serializing the array, saving it, loading it, then only deserializing each structure as it is processed (rather than the whole array)

Does anyone have any recommendations to improve performance in this situation? It seems like it would be a common problem.

Comment: It may not be an option, but you could consider playing with how you store data in the structs. For example, arrays of structs with many fields will be less efficient than a single struct with arrays for fields. In general, anything that groups the data into contiguous blocks in memory should be faster. Also, if you only need to load/update a subset of your variables, just load/save what you need instead of everything.

Comment: @user20160 That last option is something I'm looking into. The entire array needs to be saved, and loading part of an array the recommended way (`matfile`) is taking just as long (just to call `matfile`). That's why I'm looking into serializing it, then deserializing only the needed parts (loading in the entire array as a vector of uint8s is almost instantaneous)

Comment: If this is an option for your case, you may want to convert your arrays of struct into simple arrays and back before the load/save operations.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that `getByteStreamFromArray()` and `getArrayFromByteStream()` are used by `save()` and `load()` under the hood, so your results are not very surprising to me. You might get better performance using hand-crafted serialization functions that crawl down your structs and only save what's really needed. Additional saving can possibly be achieved by compressing the saved data. You can read some implementation ideas here: http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/improving-save-performance

Note #1 - YMMV based on Matlab release, data, and platform

Note #2 - for readers who are not aware of this, `getByteStreamFromArray()` and `getArrayFromByteStream()` are both undocumented Matlab functions. The only [unofficial] explanation of their behavior, AFAIK, is provided here: http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/serializing-deserializing-matlab-data